# Как подключить input(radio) к джаваскрипт,чтобы например нажав "+",числа прибавились

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
 
 $('button').on('click',function(){
  var a,b,c,d;
  a=Number($('#val1').val());
  b=Number($('#val2').val());
  

 });


 
});
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #333;
 padding:5px;
 margin:5px;
}
form{
 border:5px green;
 background-color: #333945;
 border-style: double;
}
input{
 padding:5px;
 margin:5px;

}
button{
 padding:5px;
 margin:5px;
 color: white;
 background-color: green;
}
b{
 padding:5px;
 margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>test site</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="csstest.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jstest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form align=center>
  <b >Калькулятор</b><br>
  <input type="number" name="" id="val1"><br/>
  <input type="radio">+
  <input type="radio">-
  <input type="radio">*
  <input type="radio">/<br/>
  <input type="number" name="" id="val2"><br/>
  <button><b >Ответ</b></button>
  
  <br/>
 </form>
 
</body>
```

Comment: как сделать какое нибудь действие при выборе кнопок.Например если выбрали "+" то прибавить,если "-" то отнимать и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let localMath = {
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
  '-': (a, b) => a - b,
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
  '/': (a, b) => a / b,
};
// См. "JS объекты", "стрелочные функции"

$('button').on('click', function() {
  let a = +$('#val1').val(); // плюсик делает то же, что и Number()
  let b = +$('#val2').val();
  let key = $('[name="operation"]:checked').val();
  
  console.log( localMath[key](a, b) );
  // Из объекта localMath достается нужная функция, и вызывается с аргументами (a, b)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="val1">
<hr>
<input type="radio" value="+" name="operation" checked>+
<input type="radio" value="-" name="operation">-
<input type="radio" value="*" name="operation">*
<input type="radio" value="/" name="operation">/
<hr>
<input type="number" id="val2">
<hr>
<button><b>Ответ</b></button>
```

Вместо объекта можно использовать цепочку условий if / else

```
if( key == "+" ){
  result = a + b;
} else if( key == "-" ) {
  // ляляля...
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @AgvanGrigoryan  document не должен быть в кавычках)  `$(document)` потому что document - большой объект с множеством свойств, а `"document"` - обычная строка, такая же, как и `"Hello World"`

Comment: я вставил весь код,как поделиться или скопировать ссылку страницы.Простите что немножко туплю

Comment: сохранил что дальше,загрузка сверху пошла

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Agvan/vejfdb5h/10/

Comment: что не так то а?

Comment: @AgvanGrigoryan Код в форме, поэтому после нажатия кнопки, она обновляет страницу и ничего не происходит. Чтобы остановить такое поведение - можно или его убрать из формы, или добавить на форму `<form action="javascript:void(0)"` ну и добавить какой-нибудь элемент, куда будет выводиться результат, а не только в консоль) Так - - https://jsfiddle.net/q6o1ygd2/

Comment: да про это я думал просто решил пока так оставить.Так удобнее. Огромное спасибо за то что помогли.Без вас я бы не справился,а у вас есть инста или телега,для дальнейшей связи,я просто начинающий программист я знаю что у меня будут  еще очень много проблем,если конечно вы хотите.Ещё раз огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

наперед прошу прощение за: **а)** код проверить не могу; **б)** плохо знаю `jQuery`, потмоу что призираю

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('button').on('click',function() {
        var a = Number(document.getElementById('val1').value;
        var b = Number(document.getElementById('val2').value;
        var selectedOperator = document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked'); //берем значение выбранного радио-input

        if (!selectedOperator) return; //проверяем,если не выбран ни один радиобаттон (но проще добавить выбранный input по умолчанию)

        alert(eval(a + selectedOperator.value + b)); // c помощью eval берем арифметическою строку и превращаем её в js код
    });
});
```

но для этого еще нужно к каждому `input type="radio"` добавить одинаковые аттрибуты `name`, чтобы радиобатоны работали нужным образом (как бы объеденить в одну группу), например так:

```
<input type="radio" name="lolo">+
<input type="radio" name="lolo">-
<input type="radio" name="lolo">*
<input type="radio" name="lolo">/<br/>
```

Comment: @Agvan Grigoryan, если есть вопросы, задавайте

Comment: if (!electedOperator) - опечатка

Comment: @NeedHate, метко) спасибо

Comment: @Август, можете помочь докончить это дело буду очень благодарен,просто у меня возникли некоторые проблемы с этим кодом.Я тоже новичок в этом деле и мало чего знаю jQuery и javascript,но думаю мы справимся.Просто недоумение в некоторых моментах.Вот мой инстаграм для дальнейшей связи: https://qps.ru/ekL6J ,Телеграмм: https://qps.ru/LgkVq .Напишите мне в инсту или телегу поговорим и начнем в удобное для обеих нас время.

Comment: @AgvanGrigoryan, ну я не совсем новичок. и я ценю Ваше стремление к знаниям, но с меня отвратительный напарник, так как я социофоб. при всём Уважении, я бы уделил Вам время, но меня на долго не хватит